# Query not using foreign key indexes

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, index, postgresql-performance

I have the following schema for my database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE companies (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE employments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    company_id INT REFERENCES companies(id)
);
CREATE TABLE timetrackings (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    employment_id INT REFERENCES employments(id)
);
CREATE TABLE adjusted_timetrackings (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    adjusted_to TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_by_user BOOLEAN,
    timetracking_id INT REFERENCES timetrackings(id),
    employment_id INT REFERENCES employments(id)
);
CREATE TABLE adjusted_timetracking_suggestions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    adjusted_timetracking_id INT REFERENCES adjusted_timetrackings(id),
    status VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE INDEX ON employments (company_id);
CREATE INDEX ON timetrackings (employment_id);
CREATE INDEX ON adjusted_timetrackings (timetracking_id);
CREATE INDEX ON adjusted_timetrackings (employment_id);
CREATE INDEX ON adjusted_timetracking_suggestions (adjusted_timetracking_id);
```

For context, this are the table sizes:

```
Company.count: 23775
Timetracking.count: 13614584
AdjustedTimetracking.count: 14916369
AdjustedTimetrackingSuggestion.count: 555256
Employments.count: 79594
```

I am trying to run the following query.

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM adjusted_timetrackings
INNER JOIN employments ON adjusted_timetrackings.employment_id = employments.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN adjusted_timetracking_suggestions ON adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.adjusted_timetracking_id = adjusted_timetrackings.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN timetrackings ON timetrackings.id = adjusted_timetrackings.timetracking_id
WHERE (employments.company_id = 19799 
  AND adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user = FALSE 
  AND (
    adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.id IS NULL
    OR adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.status = 'accepted'
  ) 
  AND timetrackings.created_at != adjusted_timetrackings.adjusted_to
) OR (
  employments.company_id = 19799 
  AND adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user = FALSE 
  AND (
    adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.id IS NULL
    OR adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.status = 'accepted'
  )
  AND adjusted_timetrackings.timetracking_id IS NULL
) OR (
  employments.company_id = 19799 
  AND adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user = TRUE
)
```

The current problem is the two nested loops when scaning the `employments` and `adjusted_timetrackings` table.

What I have tried:

- adding a index on `adjusted_timetracking_suggestion` `status` column (using hash)
- adding a index on `adjusted_timetracking` `deleted_by_user` column
- getting rid of the INNER JOIN on employments by providing the employment_ids mannualy and searching it by the `adjusted_timetracking.employment_id` column

For now I have ran out of ideas of what else I can do to optimize this query or make it use the available indexes to run smoothly.

EDIT:

I have added the following index

```sql
CREATE INDEX index_adjusted_timetrackings_on_employment_id ON public.adjusted_timetrackings USING btree (employment_id) INCLUDE (id, deleted_by_user, adjusted_to, timetracking_id)
```

With that I obtained a index only scan but it did not help with the two nested loops. Here is the execution plan:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=270723.45..270723.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=312.977..317.556 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Gather  (cost=270723.34..270723.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=312.968..317.549 rows=2 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 1
        Workers Launched: 1
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=269723.34..269723.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=294.929..294.932 rows=1 loops=2)
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=20.67..269721.16 rows=874 width=0) (actual time=45.082..294.662 rows=4186 loops=2)
                    Hash Cond: (adjusted_timetrackings.id = adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.adjusted_timetracking_id)
                    Filter: (((NOT adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user) AND ((adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.id IS NULL) OR ((adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.status)::text = 'accepted'::text)) AND (timetrackings.created_at <> adjusted_timetrackings.adjusted_to)) OR ((NOT adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user) AND ((adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.id IS NULL) OR ((adjusted_timetracking_suggestions.status)::text = 'accepted'::text)) AND (adjusted_timetrackings.timetracking_id IS NULL)) OR adjusted_timetrackings.deleted_by_user)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 120238
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.00..267252.11 rows=43544 width=33) (actual time=8.664..280.291 rows=124423 loops=2)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..244172.20 rows=43544 width=25) (actual time=8.633..85.467 rows=124423 loops=2)
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on employments  (cost=0.00..1991.25 rows=232 width=8) (actual time=8.576..11.977 rows=204 loops=2)
                                      Filter: (company_id = 19799)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 39592
                                ->  Index Only Scan using index_adjusted_timetrackings_on_employment_id on adjusted_timetrackings  (cost=0.56..1036.94 rows=694 width=33) (actual time=0.008..0.322 rows=608 loops=409)
                                      Index Cond: (employment_id = employments.id)
                                      Heap Fetches: 248846
                          ->  Index Scan using timetrackings_pkey on timetrackings  (cost=0.43..0.53 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=248846)
                                Index Cond: (id = adjusted_timetrackings.timetracking_id)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=14.30..14.30 rows=430 width=48) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=0 loops=2)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on adjusted_timetracking_suggestions  (cost=0.00..14.30 rows=430 width=48) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=2)
Planning Time: 0.617 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 48
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.848 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.969 ms, Emission 15.620 ms, Total 19.437 ms
Execution Time: 319.094 ms
```

Comment: Your new plan is 25 times faster than your previous one.  **Something** certainly helped but we can't tell what it was without the buffer counts and timing.  The 'Heap Fetches: 248846' suggests that the table was not vacuumed, or that vacuuming was ineffective due to long-open snapshots.

Comment: The original plan I posted was from the production database, locally i have

before index: Execution Time: 310.002 ms
after index: Execution Time: 301.990 ms

i made sure no buffering was happening. still need to test the vacuum strategy.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. (But don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.)